# How to initialize a c++ class member

Tags: c++, qt, reference

I am new to c++ and I have the following code in VS2010 using Qt:

```
// test.h
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_test.h"
#include "testDevice.h"
#include "testControl.h"

class test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    test(QWidget *parent = 0) : control(device,0) {}
    ~test();

private:
    Ui::testClass ui;
    testDevice device;
    testControl control;
};


// test.cpp
#include "test.h"

test::test(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);    
    device.start();  
    control.start();

}    

test::~test()
{

}

// testControl.h
#pragma once

#include <QThread>
#include "testDevice.h"

class testControl : public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testControl(testDevice& device, QObject *parent = 0);

protected:
    void run(void);

private:
    testDevice device;

    ~testControl(void);
};

// testControl.cpp

#include "testControl.h"


testControl::testControl(testDevice& thisDevice, QObject *parent) : QThread(parent) 
{
}

void testControl::run(void)
{
}


testControl::~testControl(void)
{
}
```

VS2010 is saying "no appropriate default constructor available" and it marks:

```
test::test(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
```

and

```
test::~test()
```

as the error source. I have tried to use testControl as a pointer and as a reference but I got many other errors...could someone please help me out with this one and explain to me whats going on?

Comment: Your class is named 'test' how do you get to SARA? where's the code from SARA

Comment: Sorry, haha my bad, I renamed everything and this got away :P I will edit

Comment: Could you please the _exact_ error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two major issues ongoing:

1) You should probably write this constructor leaving the definition for the constructor in the header behind.

You ran into the trap of two definitions provided, one in the header, and the other in the source file.

You either need to have the declaration in the header, and definition in the source, or the declaration and definition in the header. You cannot have one declaration and two definitions distributed in the header and source files!

You had the empty definition in the header by `{}` and the other definition with `{ .... }` in the source file. How would the compiler know which one you really wanted? It cannot reliably... even if it picks up either version.

2) Also, your testControl destructor seems to be private. That is not a good idea. Change that destructor to public!

#### test.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_test.h"
#include "testDevice.h"
#include "testControl.h"

class test : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    // Only declare, do not define it here
    // Also, for completeness: you should use the "explicit" keyword in here.
    explicit test(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~test();

private:
    Ui::testClass ui;
    testDevice device;
    testControl control;
};
```

#### test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

test::test(QWidget *parent = 0)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , control(device,0)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);    
    device.start();  
    control.start();
}

test::~test()
{
}
```

#### testControl.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QThread>
#include "testDevice.h"

class testControl : public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    testControl(testDevice& device, QObject *parent = 0);
    // Change this to being _public_ rather than _private_ as in your code.
    ~testControl(void);

protected:
    void run(void);

private:
    testDevice device;
};
```

Comment: this worked! But I had to chance to public the 'device' in testControl.h ... why?

Comment: @mFeinstein: I extended my reply. That is because it is not the device, but your destructor was also under the private section!

Comment: @mFeinstein: happens. That is why we are here, right? ;-) Anything left to be answered, or you are fine with this now?

Comment: I just dont get what's wrong about the double definition....AFAIK all the methods being implemented in the .cpp have to be exposed in the .h...so having a declaration in both is expected..isnt it?

Comment: @mFeinstein: you need to have the declaration in the header, and definition in the source, or the declaration and definition in the header. You cannot have one declaration and two definitions! You had the empty definition in the header by {} and the other definition with { .... } in the source file. How would the compiler know which one you really wanted?

Comment: @mFeinstein: but also note that, this was not the only issue in your code. This would not have been enough on its enough. You need to fix the destructor as well to be public in testControl!

Comment: Ohhh now I understood what's going on...I thouhgt the {} in the initialization list is somekind of c++ thing, I didnt realized it was actually making a constructor in there! Of course it makes a lot sense now! And yes, the destructor is now public, that was a silly one, specially since I took care of this in all other classes....I wont edit the post so this can be clear enough for future readers...thanks A LOT!

Answer (score 5):

You are providing an implicitly inline definition of `test`'s constructor in the `test` class definition in the header:

```
test(QWidget *parent = 0) : control(device,0) {}
```

This is most likely what the compiler is complaining about. Besides that, you go on to provide a different definition in the `.cpp` file. You can only have *one* definition.

There are two ways to fix this.

1) implicitly inline definition of the constructor in the class definition. Modify your existing header code to call the appropriate `QMainWindow` constructor in the initialization list. And remove the constructor definition from the `.cpp` file:

```
// in test.h
test(QWidget* parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent), control(device, 0) 
{
  ui.setupUi(this);    
  device.start();  
  control.start();
}
```

2) Declare the constructor in the header, and define it in the `.cpp`:

```
// in test.h
test(QWidget* parent = 0); // declaration, no definition

// in test.cpp
test::test(QWidget* parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent), control(device, 0) 
{
  ui.setupUi(this);    
  device.start();  
  control.start();
}
```

Either of these solutions should work. What you can't have is a combination of the two, which is what your code sample exhibits.

You may also need a definition of `test::~test()`. In your code sample you only show a declaration.

Comment: I dont think I understoo 100% what you said, but still it didnt work

Comment: @mFeinstein: Then you've to show us how you instantiate a `test` object. Did you make sure you removed the `{}` in the `.h` and added a `;`?

Comment: what do you mean? it's all in there...test is a default Qt auto generated class

Comment: But I didnt had in both...just in the .h so how may I be referencing it twice?

Comment: @mFeinstein Your code sample shows that you have two definitions for the constructor. One in the header and one in the `.cpp` file. That is indisputable. If your sample does not correctly represent your real code, then please fix it so that it does.

Comment: yes, the constructor is referenced in both...isnt it the right thing to do? Like the .h present the interfaces of the .cpp?

Comment: @mFeinstein: please read our answers again. It is wrong, but that was not the only issue in your code. Glad it works now though. :)

Comment: @mFeinstein I tried to clarify my answer. In a nutshell, you are currently not only declaring the constructor in the header, you are also *defining* it, i.e. giving it an implementation. So you have two implementations lying around. In case it wasn't clear, a function's *definition* is C++ speak for its implementation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your edit clarified it a lot for me, but since Laszlo got first he got the checkmark :P

Answer (score 0):

When a class is constructed, all the data members are constructed as well. If there is a default constructor for a particular data member, that one is executed.

If you need to execute a specific non-default constructor, you must use the member initialisation list in order to construct that particular data member.

I suspect that your problem is with either your

```
testDevice device;
testControl control;
```

data members, or both.

What are the available constructors for both these classes? If there are no default constructors available, you must initialise them in the members' initialisation list, supplying appropriate parameter arguments.

Comment: 'testDevice device' is working fine, and it has a default contructor...I just added 'testControl control' to the code and this class doesnt have a default constructor, so I added an initialization list for it as I showed in the code..but its not working that what bugs me...any ideas?

Comment: What is the constructor, what arguments are you passing, and what is the error you're getting?